# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token при работе с canvas

Tags: javascript

Код:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var canavs.onmousedown = onmd();
var canavs.onmousemove = onmm();
var canavs.onmouseup = onmup();
```

Chrome (другое пока не тестил) выдаёт:

> 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .'

и ошибка в строчке - `var canavs.onmousedown = onmd();`. Закомментировал ту строку, и он ругнулся на следующую. Как исправить?

Comment: Отпечатку в своём коде исправил. Не помогло. Ошибка осталась прежней

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Опечатка. Не can**a**vs, а canv**a**s.

Ну и убрать все лишние "var" из строк 2-4, т.к. это уже не объявление переменной.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.onmousedown = onmd();
canvas.onmousemove = onmm();
canvas.onmouseup = onmup();

function onmd() {
    console.log("smth");
}
function onmm() {
    console.log("smth");
}
function onmup() {
    console.log("smth");
}
```